# BigQuery SQL: filter on event sequence

Tags: sql, filter, count, google-bigquery, sequence

I want to count, for each `app_id`, how many times the `event_type`: `store_app_view` was followed by the `event_type`: `store_app_download` for the same user ("followed" meaning the `event_time_utc` of `store_app_view` is older than `event_time_utc` of `store_app_download`).

Sample data:

```
WITH 
`project.dataset.dummy_data_init` AS (SELECT event_id FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 10000)) event_id),

`project.dataset.dummy_data_completed` AS (SELECT event_id,
    user_id[OFFSET(CAST(20 * RAND() - 0.5 AS INT64))] user_id,
    app_id[OFFSET(CAST(100 * RAND() - 0.5 AS INT64))] app_id,
    event_type[OFFSET(CAST(6 * RAND() - 0.5 AS INT64))] event_type,
    event_time_utc[OFFSET(CAST(26 * RAND() - 0.5 AS INT64))] event_time_utc
  FROM `project.dataset.dummy_data_init`, 
     (SELECT GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 20) user_id),
     (SELECT GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 100) app_id),
     (SELECT ['store_app_view', 'store_app_view', 'store_app_download','store_app_install','store_app_update','store_fetch_manifest'] event_type),
     (SELECT GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2020-01-01 00:00:00', '2020-01-26 00:00:00',
                                INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS event_time_utc))

Select * FROM `project.dataset.dummy_data_completed`
```

Thanks!

Comment: . . Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to count, for each app_id, how many times the event_type: store_app_view was followed by the event_type: store_app_download.

Your provided query seems to have almost no connection to this question, so I'll ignore it.

For each user/app pair, you can get the rows that matching your conditions using `GROUP BY`:

```
select user_id, app_id
from t
group by user_id, app_id
having min(case when event_type = 'store_app_view' then event_time end) <
       max(case when event_type = 'store_app_download' then event_time end);
```

To get the total for each `app`, use a subquery or CTE:

```
select app_id, count(*)
from (select user_id, app_id
      from t
      group by user_id, app_id
      having min(case when event_type = 'store_app_view' then event_time end) <
             max(case when event_type = 'store_app_download' then event_time end)
     ) ua
group by app_id;
```